# HTTP 413 Request Entity too Large 

Tags: http, drupal, apache2, php, httpd.conf

I am currently unable to post very large files using the Drupal FileField Source (remote url option) on a custom file field in drupal 7 (7.15). The file is uploading to the tmp directory successfully but failing when it attempts to post. The file size is **870Mb** (A **510mb** file has posted successfully.).

I receive the following error in **access_log**:

`83.000.15.200 - - [02/Oct/2012:12:30:14 +0000] "POST /file/ajax/field_video_source/und/0/form-i6gTPc5LlZsQxKpgO43eaLGjh7dgWqHjQ6TPZD9SRmY HTTP/1.1" 500 413`

I assume I am interpreting this error correctly as a **413 Request Entity Too Large**

I have configured php.ini with the following settings:

`post_max_size = 1800M` 
`max_execution_time = 3600 (i know that's overkill)` 
`memory_limit = 1750M` 
`max_input_time = -1 (unlimited)`

In addition I have attempted to set the `LimitRequestBody` value to 0 in php.conf using the following:

`<Files *.php>`
`SetOutputFilter PHP`
`SetInputFilter PHP`
`LimitRequestBody 0`
`</Files>`

This didn't appear to help.

The server is running Centos 6.3, Apache/2.2.15, PHP 5.3.3 with 2GB Ram and 40GB disk.

I can't believe it should be struggling with that size file (~800mb) and those server settings?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the http.conf if so you could try this.

This has been the issue for me sometimes to upload with over 500mb. Although  I strongly suggest you should try and get it working with
the setting SecRequestBodyAccess "On".

I had to edit the Apache config file (http.conf) and change

```
SecRequestBodyAccess On
```

to

```
SecRequestBodyAccess Off
```

EDIT:

IF i remember correctly you could try the following.

SET

```
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit , the maximum value is 1073741824 (1Gb)
```