# Error 413 With Drupal Services

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7

I am a new to Drupal and working since 7 days. I got to work on services module to make webservices from existing drupal website.

**What I did so far**

I have installed variuos dependencies for Drupal Services and its working fine. I want to implement rest webservices from existing website.

**My Problem**

I am trying to get user friends which are coming from a specific view with following code. My login webservice is working fine and I am using session variables in the CURLOP_COOKIE

```
// cURL
$curl = curl_init($request_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', $csrf_header)); // Accept JSON response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Do a regular HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);  // Ask to not return Header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_session); // use the previously saved session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Check if login was successful
if ($http_code == 200) {
  // Convert json response as array
  $node = json_decode($response);
}
else {
  // Get error msg
  $http_message = curl_error($curl);
  
  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo "<br /><br /><b>last Curl Info using curl_getinfo function</b><br /><br />";
echo $cookie_session;
print_r($info);
 echo "<br /><br />";
echo "<b>Error I am getting</b><br /><br />";
  echo $http_message; 
  //die($http_message);
}
```

I am getting "The requested URL returned error: 413"

you can please have a look at url to see all the request info http://stagetesting.com/trainer/xmls/user_friends.php

I have checked last Curl Info using curl_getinfo function but that seems ok.

Please help me with this

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 413 Request Entity too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691381/http-413-request-entity-too-large) 
I don't know if this works but you can find a lot of post like this searching dupral+413

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 413 means data stream sent by the client is too large. Please share your sample $request_url.

Also which parameters are you sending with post request? I can't see post parameters.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "params")
```